# Cannot start X on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, xorg

I have been trying to run X on my Ubuntu 14.04 for a few hours now, without any success.

At start, there is no X at all :

```
ps -aux | grep X
ubuntu    2041  0.0  0.0  10460   924 pts/0    S+   17:46   0:00 grep --color=auto X
```

Logged as `ubuntu`, I am trying to start X :

```
startx


X.Org X Server 1.15.1
Release Date: 2014-04-13
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
Build Operating System: Linux 3.2.0-76-generic x86_64 Ubuntu
Current Operating System: Linux ip-172-31-41-176 3.13.0-107-generic #154-Ubuntu SMP Tue Dec 20 09:57:27 UTC 2016 x86_64
Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-107-generic root=UUID=d5ae32c8-bb78-4c1d-8750-929505dcc999 ro console=tty1 console=ttyS0
Build Date: 12 February 2015  02:49:29PM
xorg-server 2:1.15.1-0ubuntu2.7 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support) 
Current version of pixman: 0.30.2
    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
(==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Wed Jan 11 17:50:07 2017
(==) Using config file: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf"
(==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
Initializing built-in extension Generic Event Extension
Initializing built-in extension SHAPE
Initializing built-in extension MIT-SHM
Initializing built-in extension XInputExtension
Initializing built-in extension XTEST
Initializing built-in extension BIG-REQUESTS
Initializing built-in extension SYNC
Initializing built-in extension XKEYBOARD
Initializing built-in extension XC-MISC
Initializing built-in extension SECURITY
Initializing built-in extension XINERAMA
Initializing built-in extension XFIXES
Initializing built-in extension RENDER
Initializing built-in extension RANDR
Initializing built-in extension COMPOSITE
Initializing built-in extension DAMAGE
Initializing built-in extension MIT-SCREEN-SAVER
Initializing built-in extension DOUBLE-BUFFER
Initializing built-in extension RECORD
Initializing built-in extension DPMS
Initializing built-in extension Present
Initializing built-in extension DRI3
Initializing built-in extension X-Resource
Initializing built-in extension XVideo
Initializing built-in extension XVideo-MotionCompensation
Initializing built-in extension SELinux
Initializing built-in extension XFree86-VidModeExtension
Initializing built-in extension XFree86-DGA
Initializing built-in extension XFree86-DRI
Initializing built-in extension DRI2
Loading extension GLX
Loading extension NV-GLX
Loading extension NV-CONTROL
xinit: connection to X server lost

waiting for X server to shut down (EE) Server terminated successfully (0). Closing log file.
```

Here is my /etc/X11/xorg.conf:

```
# nvidia-xconfig: X configuration file generated by nvidia-xconfig
# nvidia-xconfig:  version 367.57  (buildmeister@swio-display-x64-rhel04-13)  Mon Oct  3 21:42:19 PDT 2016

Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0"
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Unknown"
    HorizSync       28.0 - 33.0
    VertRefresh     43.0 - 72.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BusID          "0:3:0"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "AllowEmptyInitialConfiguration" "True"
    Option         "UseDisplayDevice" "0"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Virtual     1920 1080
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

I do not install X usually on my remote server, therefore I do not have any idea about how to solve this problem. Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `xinit` did the trick !

Hope it will help.

Comment: Would you mind expanding this answer a bit, please?  For future readers, how did you go about updating xinit?